# Gerund vs. infinitive: are both forms acceptable for the following examples?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

**1.) It is a lesser evil to have *x* than to have *y*.**

**2.) Having *x* is a lesser evil than having *y*.**

Which of them are incorrect?

Comment: I can't explain why, but for me the first option sounds a bit formal and pompous, and the second is the more natural of the two.

Comment: 3) Neither are incorrect. But I agree with JavaLatte, the second one sounds more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Either option is perfectly good.

You can, if you want, cut out a few words and still make perfect sense.

> It is a lesser evil to have X than Y.
>
> Having X is a lesser evil than Y.